# При нажатии получить значения двух разных селекторов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью jQuery получить при нажатии на label его html содержимое и одновременно получить атрибут `value` у `<input>`

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" />
    <label for="radio1">Текст radio кнопки №1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2"  />
    <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="3"  />
    <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. при нажатии на первую кнопку должны получить value "1" и html "Текст radio кнопки №1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  var labelText = $(this).next('label').html()
  console.log('Значение:' + inputValue + ', текст метки: ' + labelText);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" />
    <label for="radio1">Текст radio кнопки №1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2"  />
    <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="3"  />
    <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[next](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) - Возвращает элементы, которые находятся непосредственно после каждого из выбранных элементов. В данном случае это метка `label`, которая идет сразу после нажатой кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.radio_buttons input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e){ // Слушаем клик на кнопки
    // this.value - значение кнопки
    // $(this).next() - следующий элемент, т. е. label; html() - содержимое label'а
    $('#log').html(`Input value: ${this.value}<br />\nLabel value: ${$(this).next().html()}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" />
    <label for="radio1">Текст radio кнопки №1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2"  />
    <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="3"  />
    <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id='log'></div>
```